# jQuery run function after everything has run

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add `colspan` with jQuery to an element. If I insert this function into console in Chrome then it works fine, but if I put it in document ready and run it in the script then nothing happens. This function should run after all scripts have run if possible. Any tips will help, no access to HTML.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#fieldset_Q8aGrid td:eq(4)").attr('colSpan',3)
});
```

Comment: Add full code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have some asynchronous scripts running which add the content after your code runs. If you do not have access to that other code, then the most pragmatic solution is to try from time to time until it succeeds:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var timer = setInterval(function () {
        if ($("#fieldset_Q8aGrid td:eq(4)").attr('colSpan',3).length) {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }, 500); // check every half-second.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you have some async code in your program that, for example, create dynamic HTML. This is the case if you don't know when all the functions will completely execute.

We can split this problem into two parts.

1. If you call a function X after a sync code Y, X will happen after Y.
2. But if you have call a function X after an async code Y, you don't know what will execute first.

To solve 1) you just have to put your code at the end of your script.
To solve 2) you have to use jQuery's deferred and when to explicitly tell your program: execute this when X, Y, Z is done.

Quick explanation (and quite not precise) of what a promise is:

> A promise is an object with a then method (thenable). The then method
>   can receive a function that will be called when the promise is
>   resolved

From an animation you can use the *.promise()* method to create a promise that will be resolved when the animation is done.

```
  var animationPromise = $('h1')
    .css({'left': '0', 'position' : 'relative'})
    .animate({'left': '20px'}, 700, 'linear')
    .promise()
```

If you are making a call to a service, the jQuery's *post*, *get* and *ajax*, return a promise

```
  // save the promise for later use
  var asyncPromise = $.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
  // execute some the function that uses this data
  asyncPromise.then(function(users) { /* do something with the data */ })
```

Maybe, you have some functionality that is neither an AJAX or an animation, in this case you can create your own promise. For example, this promise is resolved from a setTimeout.

```
  var backgroundChange = $.Deferred()
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('body').css('background', 'lightblue')
    backgroundChange.resolve(true)
  }, 3000) /* Please note that backgroundChange 
              doesn't know that it will be resolved after 3 seconds */
```

Later on, you can use *.when(...)* to create a promise that is resolved when a set of promises are resolved.

```
  $.when(asyncPromise, backgroundChange, animationPromise)
    .then(function() {
    $('.container').css('color', 'blue')
    //alert('Everything is done!');
  })
```

Here is a working example that solves the two problems https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JWBXLd?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

You can either rearrange your scripts to change their order, or go with window.load:

```
$(window).load(function() {
// code
});
```

But this will fire after literally all your page is loaded. Even images. So it'll be better to go with the first approach.